# flexsider not loading on production

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to make a slider using flexsider but it is not loading on production. It is working well on development. I am getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).flexslider is not a function

Here is the link to website: https://mybagicha.herokuapp.com/

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    slideshowSpeed: 4000,
    animationSpeed: 600,
    controlNav: false,
    directionNav: true,
    controlsContainer: ".flex-container" // the container that holds the flexslider
  });
});
```

Comment: If something works locally, but not when published to your live server it generally means that you've got an issue with the paths you use to include the JS files. The error would indicate the same, as the FlexSlider library has not been loaded correctly.

Comment: Extending @RoryMcCrossan answer, It can also happen when you have any broken js.

Comment: so can you tell me where am I doing wrong? I have given the link to the website. If you want I can provide the code

Comment: try to compile assets locally in production environment and run your website in production environment locally It will help you

Comment: Possibly if declared `jQuery` two times then show the error, this is one reason out of many

Answer (score 0):

That means `jQuery` is not defined. If you load `jQuery` twice that's also happened the error, try figure out that.

And try to the following added `$` to the

```
jQuery(window).load(function($) { 
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    //Code here
  });
});
```

Hope to help

Comment: This didn't work. Actually, I was not loading flex slider properly on production